# laravel named routing for package

Tags: php, laravel-5, package, laravel-routing

I have been working with laravel 5 for package development.So i created a package with composer as 'lakshmajim/testview'.

- then I have pulled to [github](https://github.com/lakshmajim/testview)
- then I have linked it to [Packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/lakshmajim/testview)

the I have cloned that package for testing by creating fresh laravel project

```
composer require lakshmajim/testview dev-master
```

then updated ***composer.json*** main file like this

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "lakshmajim\\testview\\": "vendor/lakshmajim/testview/src"   
    }
},
```

then i have done

```
composer dumpautoload 
composer update 
php artisan vendor:publish
```

My routes (php artisan route:list)

```
    +--------+----------+-----------------+-------------------------+------------+
|Domain|Method | URI              |Name| Action                                      | Middleware |
    +--------+----------+-----------------+------+----------+------------+
|     | GET|HEAD| /              |     | Closure                       
|     | GET|HEAD| accessurl/{str}|     | lakshmajim\testview\TestviewController@index | |    
|     | GET|HEAD| hi             |     | App\Http\Controllers\Controller@e            |            |
```

When I tried to access 
**`http://localhost:8000/accessurl/any%20parameter%20here`** 
**it works** fine and shows result.

my controller file

```
use Redirect;

class Controller extends BaseController
{ 
        public function e()
        {
            $url='accessurl/strtestpackage';
            return Redirect::route($url);
        }
}
```

**The problem** is when I 'm trying to access package route form controller it shows following error

```
`**InvalidArgumentException in UrlGenerator.php line 296: Route [accessurl/str] not defined**`.
```

**QUESTION**    How can I able to access named route present in vendor directory form controller?   (How can I use  **vendor/lakshmajim/testview/src/routes.php** file from **app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php**?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `route()` method takes the route name as a parameter. As I can see, your package has no route name.
You can just use `redirect()`

```
return redirect('/url/here');
```

Also in your `routes.php`, you can define the route names using `as` keyword. Check documentation [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#named-routes).